# OnCollisionEnter2D and OnCollisionStay2D not detecting anything or being called unless i turn off 'Is Trigger'

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, collision-detection

I was attempting to create a simple button prompt where when you are inside a 2d box colider it will give you the option to press the button within that range, below is the short code used to test this.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("ENTER");
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Debug.Log("Stay");
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("PLayer Detected");
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
                Debug.Log("E pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this does not output any Debug Messages at all. Maybe i have a misundestanding of the Is Trigger function and colliders in general but when i have it turned off it does nothing, when i have it on it acts as a box (which i dont want) but when i push againsts the box it will send out the debug messages.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A Trigger collider does not generate collision response](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/181370/39518) (which is what the `OnCollisionEnter`/`Stay`/`Exit` messages and their `2D` versions handle).

It only participates in overlap checks, which are handled by the `OnTriggerEnter`/`Stay`/`Exit` messages and their `2D` versions.

So replace your code with:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("ENTER");
}

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Stay");
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("PLayer Detected");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
            Debug.Log("E pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Just watch out that in the physics step (when these collision/trigger callback messages are fired), the key press events you're receiving are those from the *previous* frame. In recent Unity versions, the freshest input isn't available until `Update`.

Also note that these messages are sent only if one of the participating colliders is attached to a `Rigidbody` / `Rigidbody2D` - [check the collision action matrix for the full details](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! That works!